# android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, classcastexception

I'm trying to change a `LinearLayout` from another class, but when i run this code:

```
public class IRC extends PircBot {

ArrayList<String> channels;
ArrayList<Integer> userCount;
ArrayList<String> topics;

LinearLayout channelLayout;
Context context;

public IRC(Context ctx) {
    this.setName("xxxx");
    channels = new ArrayList<String>();
    userCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    topics = new ArrayList<String>();

    context = ctx;

    channelLayout = (LinearLayout) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.channels);
}
```

i get a `ClassCastException`

context is the Main activity that extends `Activity` passed with a getApplicationContext();

**LOGCAT**

```
05-08 17:53:55.102    3736-3799/g.d.allinonechat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5357
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at g.d.xxx.IRC.<init>(IRC.java:34)
        at g.d.xxx.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:49)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Remove that try catch and Post your logcat..

Comment: You shouldn't need `(Activity)` since you are using the `Activity Context`. Along with the logcat, you might want to post how you are passing the `Context`.

Comment: What is IRC.java line no :34??

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You are passing the Application `Context` not the `Activity Context` with

```
getApplicationContext();
```

Wherever you are passing it pass `this` or `ActivityName.this` instead.

Since you are trying to cast the `Context` you pass (Application not Activity as you thought) to an `Activity` with

```
(Activity)
```

you get this exception because you can't cast the Application to `Activity` since Application is not a sub-class of `Activity`.

Comment: This is an answer? is the same that log but with a lot of lines
"ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity" 
A solution for me is to use "this" from an Activity

Comment: @vLopez I don't understand your question. But yes `this` will work in an `Activity` which is why I suggested passing that since the OP was not in an `Activity`

Comment: I was using context = getApplicationContext()  changed it to context = this.  solved the problem.

Comment: Very good answer. This was a no nonsense answer. I was getting this error for a few day and when I read this answer, I corrected the association of context to the solution provided.

Comment: Saved all of us. Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

in case your project use dagger, and then this error show up
you can add this at android manifest

```
   <application
        ...
        android: name = ".BaseApplication"
        ...> ...
```

Comment: I'm not using dagger but it works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

In my case, when I'm in an activity that extends from `AppCompatActivity`, it did not work`(Activity) getApplicationContext ()`, I just put`this` in its place.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because the parameter required is Activity and you are passing it the Application.
So, either you cast application to the Activity like: `(Activity)getApplicationContext();`
Or you can just type the Activity like: `MyActivity.this`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I just put `android:name=".CustomBaseClass"` inside the activity tag instead of the application tag inside the manifest, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one.

```
override fun registerWith( registry: PluginRegistry) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry as FlutterEngine)       
    //registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin")
    }
```

I think this one is far better solution than creating a new class.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when checking for internet connection in my viewmodel.
The error in my logcat:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.newsapplication.util.AppApplication in viewmodel
```

I added this line in the manifest and my application worked just fine.

```
  android:name="com.example.newsapplication.util.AppApplication"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just put add name property inside the `application` tag in the `Manifest` file

```
<application
    android:name=".TodoApplication"
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I removed the line `android:name ="<some_name>"` and it worked. Looks like it was looking for a class with the name that was provided earlier whereas my Project does not have the class.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I deleted the android:name=".TodoApplication" from application and added it inside the activity tag.

```
<activity android:name=".BaseApplication"/>
```

Ensure you delete from the Application tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android) in my project. I found problem at Module class. I converted SingletonComponent to ActivityComponent. I read that we shouldn't inject Activity to object that marked as @Singleton.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you have a question, please post it yourself

Comment: Pardon me, but it's not clear (to me, at least) whether you are answering the question or asking another question. Did converting `SingletonComponent` to `ActivityComponent` solve the problem?

Comment: yes solved my problem. Sorry for confusion. I just wanted to say While I'm implementing Hilt my module occurs this error so I searched and found this solution.