# BaseAdapter getLayoutInflater giving runtime exception

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a class postedJobHistory (Fragment):

```
public class PostedJobHistory extends Fragment {
    String employerName;
    private List<ParseObject> jobDetails;
    Context context;
    public PostedJobHistory() {}
    public PostedJobHistory(Context context, String employerName) {
        this.context = context;
        this.employerName = employerName;
    }
    ListView listViewJobHistory;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View jobsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_posted_job_history, container, false);
        listViewJobHistory = (ListView) jobsView.findViewById(R.id.listViewJobHistory);

        if(jobDetails==null){
            jobDetails=new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
            EmployerHistory jobsQuery=new EmployerHistory();
            jobDetails = jobsQuery.getJobHistory(employerName);
        }

        listViewJobHistory.setAdapter(new TimelineList(context, jobDetails));

        return jobsView;
    }
}
```

For the Adapter I have  this class in the same .java file as above:

```
class TimelineList extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<ParseObject> elements;
    Context mContext;
    public TimelineList(Context mContext, List<ParseObject> elements) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.elements = elements;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return elements.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ParseObject getItem(int position) {
        return elements.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

//this line is giving runtime exception
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            View row;
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.job_history_listitem, parent, false);
            TextView title, detail;
            title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            detail = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.detail);
            title.setText(getItem(position).get("JobName").toString());
            title.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            detail.setText(getItem(position).get("updatedAt").toString());
            return (row);
        }
    }
```

> 07-28 02:06:12.424  17392-17392/com.example.ankit.job_depot
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.ankit.job_depot, PID: 17392
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
>               at com.example.ankit.job_depot.TimelineList.getView(PostedJobHistory.java:80)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
>               at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
>               at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1455)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546303/android-app-application-cannot-be-cast-to-android-app-activity) it is given that Context cannot be casted to an Activity as it is not its subclass. I am not sure how to resolve this issue.

Comment: change Context to Activity in Adapter

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity` it's clear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
public PostedJobHistory(Context context, String employerName) {
    this.context = context;
    this.employerName = employerName;
}
```

Fragment should have no argument constructor

Secondly you can get context of activity using `getActivity()` in 
`onCreateView`

```
listViewJobHistory.setAdapter(new TimelineList(getActivity(), jobDetails));
```

Then in Constructor of your adapter

```
LayoutInflate inflater;
public TimelineList(Context mContext, List<ParseObject> elements) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.elements = elements;
}
```

If you need to pass data from activity to fragment

[Send data from activity to fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Also you should be using a `ViewHolder` pattern

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Note: **All subclasses of Fragment must include a public no-argument constructor.**

Source :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Thanks for pointing out how to pass data from activity to fragment, android studio was giving warning but I was giving red flags, but I was not sure how to do it. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Bharthan i hope you have no arg constructor. check the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

You must be trying to pass `getApplicationContext()` instead of `Activity` to the constructor of your `fragment`.Try passing the activity instance instead of application context.

To `PostedJobHistory` `constructor`, pass the parent activity instance using `this`

Comment: `this` will not help cause `this` refers to `Fragment`. Also op has Fragment with a constructor. that is a bigger mistake

Comment: I am not telling to add 'this' in fragment constructor.From the activity code, where he is creating this fragment instance.

Comment: but adapter is initialized in fragment

Comment: That is fine.If he pass an activity instance to the construtor, context will be holding it.In that case,adapter will be having that activity reference only since he is passing context to the adapter

Comment: constructor of fragment??

Answer (score -2):

You are casting Context into Activity that's why you getting error.

Please pass Activity in parameter of constructor instead of Context

```
Activity mActivity ;
    public TimelineList(Activity mActivity, List<ParseObject> elements) {
        this.mActivity= mActivity;
        this.elements = elements;
    }
```

Comment: `java.lang.Object
   ↳  android.content.Context
      ↳  android.content.ContextWrapper
         ↳  android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
            ↳  android.app.Activity`