# Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity while checking permission

Tags: java, android

I am creating a call application i created an adapter for Recycler view on requesting CALL_PHONE there is showing the error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                     Process: in.welcomeyou.merchant, PID: 14890                                                                    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EnquiryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Enquiry enquiry = enquiryList.get(position);
    holder.domainTextView.setText(enquiry.getDomain());
    holder.nameTextView.setText(enquiry.getName());
    holder.commentsTextView.setText(enquiry.getComments());
    holder.dateTextView.setText(enquiry.getDate());

    holder.callBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mCtx, CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                        Constants.CALL_PHONE);
                return;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:123456"));
            mCtx.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });


}
```

Comment: what is the type of mCtx ? You may want to take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546303/android-app-application-cannot-be-cast-to-android-app-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are passing context to this adapter use ActivityName.this or this .
Maybe now you passed

```
getApplicationContext();
```

And you get this exception because you can not cast the Application to Activity because Application is not a sub-class of Activity.

Comment: its calling from 
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private void getEnquiries() {

EnquiryAdapter adapter = new EnquiryAdapter(getApplication(), enquiryList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Just Pass your ActivityClassname.this on place getApplication.

Comment: ok just write you adapter definition like this:EnquiryAdapter adapter = new EnquiryAdapter(DashboardActivity.this, enquiryList);

Answer (score 1):

Please write this as below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:123456"));
((YourActivityName)mContext).startActivity(intent);
```