# android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: android

I've read [android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546303/android-app-application-cannot-be-cast-to-android-app-activity) but I didn't solve my problem. I tried to write in code

```
totalebevuto = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.totalebevuto);
```

as suggested in the post but I get an error.

```
    public class MyReceiver2 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    WordListOpenHelper mDB;
    WordListAdapter mAdapter;

    TextView totalebevuto;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        mDB = new WordListOpenHelper(context);
        // AGGIUNGERE LA DATA AL DATABASE
        totalebevuto = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.totalebevuto);
        mDB.insert_daily(Integer.parseInt(totalebevuto.getText().toString()));

        mDB.clear();

        mAdapter = new WordListAdapter(context, mDB);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Toast.makeText(context, "OnReceive2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Comment: show your full code

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I posted all the code

Answer (score 0):

I think my whole approach to getting value from the MainActivity was wrong. I saved the value I need in SharedPreferences and then retrieved it in the receiver.