# Use the startActivityForResult method in a class that extends View and not extends AppCompatActivity?

Tags: startactivityforresult

How can I use the  `startActivityForResult` method in a class that extends `View` and not extends `AppCompatActivity`?

```
public class ContentsElement extends View {
    
    public ContentsElement(final Context context, final String text, final int requestCode, FlexboxLayout cl) {
        super(context);
            final TextView mu = new TextView(getContext());
        mu.setText(text);
        cl.addView(mu);

        mu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        mu.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

                Context context = getContext();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

                startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);

            }
        });
    
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repalce `startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);` with:

```
((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at 765.ContentsElement$1.onClick(ContentsElement.java:65)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)

Comment: It looks like you're passing "getApplicationContext", not the activity context. Take a look at this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23546802/6651763

Comment: Thanks! Can I use onActivityResult in the same class?

Comment: You use it where you expect to retrieve the result.